# Remove duplicate values just once and then sum array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, duplicates, filtering

I want to leave duplicates inside my array and only delete one occurrence when a value is found more than once.

Given an array of:

```
$array = ['+5', '+5', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+5', '+5'];
```

`+5` and `+3` each occur four times.  I want to remove just one of the `+5` values and just one of the `+3` values, then find the sum of the remaining values.

```
$duplicate = ['+5', '+3'];
$array = ['+5', '+5', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+5', '+5'];

$i = 0;
foreach ($duplicate as $dup) {
    if (strpos($duplicate[$i], '+') !== false) {
        $duplicate[$i] = preg_replace('/[^0-9,:]/', '', $duplicate[$i]);
        $duplicate[$i] = "-$duplicate[$i]";
    }
    $i++;
}
$sum = array_merge($duplicate, $array);
$end_value = array_sum(array_values($sum));
var_export($end_value);
```

For my input, the final sum should be `24` (15 + 9).

Comment: I don't understand `the cards count them self`.  Please reinforce the required logic by presenting your exact desired result based on your sample input.  Do you expect this? https://3v4l.org/24GRd

Comment: I see `explode()` being called, but I don't see `$expode` being used anywhere.  Are we working from a hyphen-delimited string (`$player_cards[$i2]`)?  If so, I can potentially remove a duplicate without iterated function calls.  Please explain further.

Comment: $player_cards was just a list of cards,   explode() was not needed i didn't mean to add it in the code. thank you for your help but i did find a way to work around the problem by creating a $duplicate_array, and adding duplicates to the array.  i then took there opposite values and add them to the main $add_p1_f1 array

Comment: There is often more than one way to solve a programming problem.  It is important to future researchers that your question is super clear.  Please added the requested details to your question and confirm whether my solution delivers your expected output.

Comment: No.  You are not understanding Stack Overflow page design.  Please take the [tour]. You are making a mess and not making a complete question as I've asked.  You are ignoring my request to confirm my demo link provides the desired result.  This is the new required output, right? https://3v4l.org/M20nU

Comment: Thanks for the info i didn't know about Online PHP editor, i made a working version so you can see what i wanted. again thanks~

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember what value you deleted from the array.
In below script you save te value if it apperas at the first time, in `$existsValues` array. If you find  the same value again you delete it (and save information that you did it in `$deletedValues` array). If value exists in both arrays then you just do nothing with it. In this way you delete always the second occurence of the value and nothing more.

```
$existsValues = [];
$deletedValues = [];
foreach ($add_array as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value, $existsValues)) {
        $existsValues[] = $value;
    } else {
        if (!in_array($value, $deletedValues)) {
            $deletedValues[] = $value;
            unset($add_array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well what i did was add all duplicates into $duplicates_array, i then took them and flip there value so that (+5) was turn into (-5)  and (+3) = (-3)... i then just used array_merge( $duplicate[] ,$add_p1_f1[] )   and    array_sum(array_values($add_p1_f1[] ));

Comment: If the task ultimately ends with summing the card values, then `array_values()` is not needed.  Resolving techniques must not be posted as comments.  Resolving advice should be posted as an explained answer.

Comment: i have a working code i posted as the answer, thanks to mickmackusa for the Online PHP editor. you can take a look and see what i wanted to do ^^ anyways thanks for your answer and help!

Answer (score 0):

The task of summing all values and omitting just one occurrence of all repeated values can be done without conditionally maintaining a duplicate array and definitely doesn't require regex.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M20nU))

```
$array = ['+5', '+5', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+3', '+5', '+5'];

foreach (array_count_values($array) as $value => $count) {
    if ($count > 1) {
        unset($array[array_search($value, $array)]);
    }
}
var_export(array_sum($array));    // 24
```

The above groups values and counts their occurrences.  Then it removes just one of the values when the values occurs more than once.  Then sum the altered array.

---

Or you can boil it down to a mathematical process: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ipEaE))

```
$total = 0;
foreach (array_count_values($array) as $value => $count) {
    $total += $value * ($count - ($count > 1));
}
echo $total;
// 24
```

^ if the count is greater than 1, subtract 1 from the multiplier. (if `$count > 1`, then `true` is treated as `1`; otherwise `0`).

Comment: @Ulta I'll recommend that you use my second snippet in your project if you don't actually need to modify the input array.